# ios - Use Cell design in different Tables

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cells

I'm creating an ios app with different tables. But some of this tables use the same cells. Is there a way to design the cell with all the constrains and stuff at a central point? Because I don't want to copy every cell into all the tables and update them when I change something. Or should I do this all programmatically? (I don't really want this, it's much to do)

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, subclass `UITableViewCell` and register that cell to every table.

Comment: Use Xib for that and you can use it each time in different tableview.
May I tell the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have many tables and some table are using the same cell, in that case, you can use Xib for that
    Go to New -> Files and add Empty interface -> Add it.
Go to interface builder and Add tableViewCell from UI elements list

Add a class of Type UITableViewCell do needed connections

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let identifier = "NameOfTableViewCellIdentifier"

    var cell: classOfTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? classOfTableViewCell
if cell == nil {
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "XibNameOfTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? classOfTableViewCell
}


       cell.outletOfUIElements..........
        return cell!
}
```

Let me know if it's work for you

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

you can make a nib of your cell, n simply load the nib in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    yourCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourCustomCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, you can make these things called xibs. It looks similar to your story board but it can be used to make views without the view controller, in simple. You can then use that xib in you code by doing

`Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(enter your params here).first as! YourCell`

Your cell is just the name of your subclassed tableview cell, if you didnt subclass it, it would just be as! TableViewCell

Comment: Can I combine these xibs with my storyboard?

Comment: No i dont believe you can,  what you can do is in your cell for row at index path, depending on what section it is, change the cell to `let cell = Bundle.ma.... what i have in my answer above` and change it according the the section number.